# Prevent event inside object function to overwrite "this"

Tags: javascript, events, object, this

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();

        this.update();
        this.render();

        lastLoop = thisLoop;
    }, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

**game.js:198Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'update'**

Why is this happening ?
"this" should relate to the Game object.

Comment: It's because setInterval-functions are  executed in global scope(window). It's  `window.setInterval()` not `Game.setInterval()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache the `this` variable, or use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    var _this = this;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();
        _this.update();
        _this.render();
        lastLoop = thisLoop;
    }, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

Or, using [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    window.setInterval((function() {
        ... 
    }.bind(this), 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

`this` in a function passed to `setInterval` refers to the global `window` object, or is `undefined` (in strict mode).

Another method, similar to the first one. Pass `this` as a parameter to the function (so that no extra local variable is used):

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    window.setInterval(function(_this) {
        var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();
        _this.update();
        _this.render();
        lastLoop = thisLoop;
    }, 1000 / this.fps, this);
};
```

Comment: Hum I tried caching `this` before with another function but it didn't work. Don't know why it does now, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    var intervalCallBack = function() {
        var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();
        this.update();
        this.render();
        lastLoop = thisLoop;
    };
    var self = this;
    window.setInterval(function(){intervalCallBack.call(self);}, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

Because of the fact that `setInterval` and `setTimeout` executes your callback in the global context, your `this` "pointer" that you used to refer to your game object is now referring to the global object (`window`) , which of course *has no method 'update'*.

Comment: Yup does works now, interessting. I'll stick to the cache method though, but keep yours in mind in case something still won't work. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, this in the scope of the function refers to the function itself. Its somewhat hard to wrap your head around scoping in JS if you're not used to it.

The easy solution is to cache the context of "this" outside the anonymous function and use that instead.

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
  var game = this;
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();
    game.update();
    game.render();
    lastLoop = thisLoop;
  }, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kmendes/awzMn/

In this case there's no way you can do that because the setInterval function has a different scope. This is what you can do:

```
Game.prototype.run = function() {
    var currentGame = this;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var thisLoop = new Date().getTime();

        currentGame.update();
        currentGame.render();

        lastLoop = thisLoop;
    }, 1000 / this.fps);
};
```